# Application Freezing using My.Computer.Network.Download("Url", "C:\downloadedfile.exe")

Tags: .net, vb.net

```
My.computer.Network.Download("Url", "C:\downloadedfile.exe"
Process.start("C:\downloadfile.exe")
```

Hi I'm using the code above but I noticed that the application freezes until the downloading process is completed. Is there any solution that can prevent freezing while downloading the file?

Comment: Use `Await` with the new `HttpClient` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.WebClient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to download the file async.

```
Dim wb As New WebClient
Addhandler wb.DownloadFileCompleted, AddressOf Completed
wb.DownloadFileAsync(url, filename)
```

When file is done this event is called

```
Private Sub Completed(sender As Object, e As AsyncCompletedEventArgs)
 'file downloaded
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer I'm currently trying it now :)